# Get all data from table using PHP different Object method

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get all value from database using PHP Object method and getting error:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Calldb::mysqli_query() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\geomaticxpms\core\Alltablevalue.php:13
>
> Stack trace: 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\geomaticxpms\manager\header.php(8):
>   Alltablevalue-
>   Getallvalue('business')
>   1 {main}   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\geomaticxpms\core\Alltablevalue.php on line 13

**I have custom auto loader file which bring all files calling through a PHP include function**

I am connecting database using (Calldb.php):

```
  class Calldb {
    public $db;
      public function __construct() {
            require_once('config.db.php');
            $this->db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABSE);
            if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Error: Could not connect to database.";
                    exit;
            }
        }
    public function __destruct() {
        mysqli_close($this->db) OR die("There was a problem disconnecting from the database.");
    }
    }
```

Get all table data (Alltablevalue.php):

```
class Alltablevalue {
public $db;
public $table;
public $data;
    function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    function Getallvalue($table){
    $this->table = $table;
    $data =  $this->db->mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM $this->table");
    if($data->num_rows > 0){
    $row = $connect->fetch_assoc();
    return $this->$row;
        }
  else { return false;}
    }
}
```

Output page:

```
include_once('functions.php');
if (!$including) exit("direct access not permitted");
//echo "<pre>";
$db = new Calldb();
$connect = new Alltablevalue($db);

$data = $connect->Getallvalue("business"); // "business" is table name
```

Please guide so I can make it work.
**I will provide all description if need.**

auto-loader class file calling through functions.php

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
});
```

Comment: Your Calldb  doesn't have a mysqli_query function

Comment: @madalinivascu , no I think it is called by line `$connect = new Alltablevalue($db);` as `$db = new Calldb();`

Comment: You need to call `$this->db->db->mysqli_query` as your classes stand.  You need to access the mysqli instance in your Calldb object.

Comment: @NigelRen thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Stop making wrappers for database connection. [MySQLi already is a damned class](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php). Learn to use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

everyone thank you for your help. I there was mistake in my code:

**Problem in "Alltablevalue.php"**

```
class Alltablevalue {
public $db;
public $table;
public $data;
    function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    function Getallvalue($table){
    $this->table = $table;
    $data =  $this->db->db->query("SELECT * FROM $this->table");
    if($data->num_rows > 0){
    $row = $data->fetch_assoc();
    return $row;
        }
  else { return false;}
    }
}
```